# What is actually stored when you store a contract in a mapping?

Tags: solidity

If I have contract called Person, say, which contains a name and an age, and another Contract called People, and the People contract looks like

```
 contract People {
      mapping(string => Person) myPeople;

      addPerson(string memory name, uint age) {
          Person person = new Person(name, age);
          myPeople[name] = person;
      }
 }
```

I'm wondering in this case, what is actually going on in the blockchain.  I understand that the statement `Person person = new Person(name, age)` will actually deploy the a new Person contract onto the blockchain (and I will pay for that).  But when I store it in the mapping via `myPeople[name] = person;`, am I storing just the contract address, or am I storing all of its data a second time?     (i.e. both in the storage for the deployed contract, and also in storage on the People contract.   If the second, it sounds like it would be a lot cheaper to just store the address.  I notice I can a retrieve `Person` from the mapping, and can call its functions without having to instantiate it, but perhaps there is some magic that behind the scenes where the contract is instantiated from its address, and which makes its possible for me to call its functions?

Comment: It's a great question. I'll start by saying that I don't know for sure. But I'm pretty confident guessing that there is NOT a copy of the contract data inside your storage. Simply because it doesen't sounds like a good plan. Think about the implications of that, you could have two supposed pointers to the same data, and it could be different. 
Either way, it could still be the case, maybe I can write some tests and check for the gas costs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual value stored in the `People` contract storage (under each item of the `myPeople` mapping) is the **address** of the deployed `Person` contract.

The `Person` contract storage is **not duplicated** in the `People` contract.

> *I can a retrieve Person from the mapping, and can call its functions without having to instantiate it*

When the `People` contract interacts with a `Person` instance, it's only using the **interface** of the `Person` contract. So the `People` contract knows what functions `Person` has, what are the expected arguments, return values, etc.

When you assign a variable from the `myPeople` mapping, Solidity instantiates a helper object that interacts with the remote `Person` contract (remember the first paragraph, the address is stored in your contract) using the **local** `Person` interface.

So yea, this is where the magic comes from. :)